# "gusto and abandon" origin

Tags: etymology, idioms, popular-refrains

While I rarely see "gusto and abandon" used in a text, it has popped up in an article I have read yesterday.

The sentence in the article says:

> "But before we plunge headfirst into the fray with gusto and abandon,
>   let's pause for a moment"

I have asked a couple of colleagues about it and all they could do is explain the meaning of it, which is "doing something with enthusiasm and without regard to fear"

My interest is knowing how these two words came together?
"Gusto" & "abandon" don't seem to fit together.

Comment: Why don’t you think _gusto_ and _abandon_ go together? They mean quite similar things and go together very well.

Comment: The usual cliché is "headlong into the fray."

Comment: The earliest uses of this string (it might even have reached weak collocation status now) that I've found are dated 1868, from [Baily's Magazine of Sports and Pastimes - Volume 15 - Page 209 and Putnam's Magazine - Volume 1 - Page 563](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22gusto+and+abandon%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1919&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=c4Z9WoLSDoq5gQbRi4CwCw).

Answer (score 1):

*Gusto* means *great energy, enthusiasm, and enjoyment that is experienced by someone taking part in an activity*. And *abandon* is a noun, not a verb, in your sentence. In this context it is a literary synonym for *extraordinary enthusiasm*. So, we can paraphrase like this: "But before we plunge headfirst into the fray *with great energy and enthusiasm*, let's pause for a moment".

Comment: Hello, Enguroo. OP asks about 'how these words came together' – the 'origin' of the string. The question itself gives the meaning 'with enthusiasm and without regard to fear', which you just echo.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your comment. I was trying to explain how the words "gusto" and "abandon" came together grammatically first of all. The OP's confusion might have been caused by "abandon", which is used as a noun not so often.

Comment: I think we have to work on the assumption that someone who visits a site aimed at linguists should be able to distinguish the verb and noun forms of 'abandon'. If they don't, the correct place for them to post is ELL (who would also expect them to have looked up the words).

Comment: Well, anyone is free to visit this site aimed at linguists and ask their questions seeking professional linguistic advice. By the way, a person who writes "I have read yesterday" might happen to be not an experienced linguist... Anyway, if the OP asks any more questions, I'll be happy to answer them.

Comment: But the sister site, ELL, was set up to deal with more basic questions, and there too a modicum of research is expected. Answering off-topic questions here sends the wrong signal to the [potential] user-base.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm not a linguist should I stop visiting and contributing to the site? I don't think it's entirely accurate, or fair, to mention that this site is aimed at linguists, after all there is a Stack Exchange site dedicated to linguists, it's [SE.Lingusitics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: And I don't think it fair (for anyone) to downvote a correct answer only because a new user has answered a question considered off-topic by some. It's not, IMHO, more could have been said about "gusto" and its collocations.  And something could have been noted about its pronunciation, quite different from its evident Italian origins. Peccato...

Comment: @Mari-Lou A You are a linguist within the pragmatic range intended in the mission statement. / I trust you will also address the others who voted to close the question on lack of reasonable research grounds, assuming you chose not to vote to close while it was still open. As for myself, I am more concerned about the problem of mediocrity, in line with the concern tchrist and others have voiced, than some others seem to be. If an answer is partly lifted from a dictionary and the answerer can't even be bothered to supply a correct link and attribution, I'll downvote.

Comment: Dear Mr.Edwin Ashworth, I believe your conclusions are hasty and wrong. You say that I am mediocre but you have no idea about who I am and what I do. You judge by a single (and by the way right) answer to a question. But of course you will not agree because you must be too self-satisfied for that.

Comment: I think the best thing about this website is that people can find practical answers to practical questions here. It doesn't look like a place for someone on an ego trip. I hope my first impression is not false.